# Integration between HP ALM and Borland SilkTest

Tags: vbscript, integration, alm, silktest

Is there a mode to execute a SilkTest Workbench script from HP ALM (SaaS)?

I know that there is a test called VAPI-XP, but I'd like to use in/out parameters, for get the final result test and the attachments that I recorded in time execution. Currently I am creating a VBScript inside HP ALM (VAPI-XP) and I call the script in the SilkTest through the command line STW.exe. But I don't know catch the final result in the Silktest script and to set in the HP ALM.

That is an example how I am working:

```
HP ALM >>> VAPI-XP (VBScript) >>> STW.exe >>> SilkTest Workbench
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Silk Test command line executor accepts both input and output parameters. For instance:

```
STW.exe -script ScriptWithParameters -variable "var1=1234" "var2=Hello" "var3=True" -outputfile C:\Temp\MyFile.txt
```

That line runs the Silk Test script called `ScriptWithParameters` assigning to the input parameters `var1`, `var2` and `var3` the values `1234`, `Hello` and `True` respectively.

It also creates (overwrites) the output file `C:\Temp\MyFile.txt`, which is a text file where each line represents a script that was executed. Each line contains a number of fields separated by a tab character (`0x9`). These fields are: script name, project name, run environment, total verifications executed, number of verification that passed, number of verifications that failed, script status, playback error message (if any) and script input parameters.

You can find more information at [Micro Focus documentation](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.workbench.doc%2FGUID-537FA318-5FC1-43F9-B638-5192205094CC.html).

Apart from that, if you use the Silk4J or Silk4Net dialect instead of Silk Test Workbench, you can invoke test scripts as regular JUnit and NUnit tests.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible using Silk Test 16. You might try contacting support to enter an enhancement request though.